# How to integrate custom meta tags with Rails 5 + webpacker + Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, ruby-on-rails-5, facebook-opengraph, webpacker

Just like in title: What is the proper way to integrate SEO stuff like Facebook OpenGraph tags in apps that use rails backend API (installed with webpacker) with a framework like Vue?

This is how part of my `config/routes.rb` looks like:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :posts, only: [:index, :show]
  end
end

get '/', to: 'front#index', format: false
get '/*path', to: 'front#index', format: false
```

For now app is designed in the way, where all requests on front-end part are handled by `vue-router`.

My `layouts/application.html` looks almost, like on the attached snippet:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <%= javascript_pack_tag 'front' %>
   <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'front' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My question is, what is the proper way to manage stuff like Facebook Open Graph when there is no straight forward access to `<head>` section?

I can't use fairly default rails stuff like `content_for` because everything happens inside script.

Or maybe am I wrong? Missing something fancy, important here?

It would be grateful to get any advice, thanks.

Comment: What did you do in the end?

Comment: Can you post what you did at end?